# Magento- Error when i go to sorting in admin panel theproducts by SKU

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.6

when i go to sorting the products in administrator panel by SKU i take this error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:845:"SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty`, `at_status`.`value` AS `status`, `at_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility`, `at_sku`.`value` AS `sku` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '89') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '95') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 0)
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_sku` ON (`at_sku`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_sku`.`attribute_id` = '68') AND (`at_sku`.`store_id` = 0) ORDER BY `sku` ASC LIMIT 20

";i:1;s:3310:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php(687): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php(1045): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, `...')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php(869): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(526): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php(90): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(618): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(624): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\ProductController.php(296): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->gridAction()
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('grid')
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#25 {main}";s:3:"url";s:126:"/homelicious/index.php/admin/catalog_product/grid/key/836f4c761c6eeda64b95dd46d98ed6b0/sort/sku/dir/asc/?ajax=true&isAjax=true";s:11:"script_name";s:22:"/homelicious/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

and then i can't go in my products only if sign out and then sign in.

then i take this

```
a:5:{i:0;s:845:"SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty`, `at_status`.`value` AS `status`, `at_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility`, `at_sku`.`value` AS `sku` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '89') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '95') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 0)
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_sku` ON (`at_sku`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_sku`.`attribute_id` = '68') AND (`at_sku`.`store_id` = 0) ORDER BY `sku` ASC LIMIT 20

";i:1;s:5626:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php(687): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php(1045): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, `...')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php(869): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(526): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php(90): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(618): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(624): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product.phtml(46): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product->getGridHtml()
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#35 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#36 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\ProductController.php(180): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#37 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->indexAction()
#38 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#39 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#40 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#41 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\app\Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#42 C:\xampp\htdocs\homelicious\index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#43 {main}";s:3:"url";s:88:"/homelicious/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/key/d7d0ed1358caec71a5669256178845c3/";s:11:"script_name";s:22:"/homelicious/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: Maybe it's just because I'm not familiar with Magento, but what on Earth am I looking at?  A stacktrace?  Where did it come from?  What code caused it?

Comment: for some reason i take this error, but i don't know. i will explain what i am doing:
1)Administrator Panel of Magento
2)Catalog-Manage Products
3)clicking under the SKU (for sorting my product)
4)After that the magento going to first page o Administrator Panel(and isn't sorting the products)
5)If i go again to Catalog-Manage Products i take this error

Comment: Sounds like this question belongs on [sf].